# Typesafe keys for a map

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

Given the following code:

```
val m: Map[String, Int] = .. // fetch from somewhere
val keys: List[String] = m.keys.toList
val keysSubset: List[String] = ... // choose random keys
```

We can define the following method:

```
def sumValues(m: Map[String, Int], ks: List[String]): Int =
  ks.map(m).sum
```

And call this as:

```
sumValues(m, keysSubset)
```

However, the problem with `sumValues` is that if `ks` happens to have a key not present on the map, the code will still compile but throw an exception at runtime. Ex:

```
// assume m = Map("two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)
sumValues(m, 1 :: Nil)
```

What I want instead is a definition for `sumValues` such that the `ks` argument should, at compile time, be guaranteed to only contain keys that are present on the `map`. As such, my guess is that the existing `sumValues` type signature needs to accept some form of implicit evidence that the `ks` argument is somehow derived from the list of keys of the map.

I'm not limited to a scala `Map` however, as any record-like structure would do. The map structure however won't have a hardcoded value, but something derived/passed on as an argument.

*Note*: I'm not really after summing the values, but more of figuring out a type signature for `sumValues` whose calls to it can only compile if the `ks` argument is provably from the list of keys the map (or record-like structure).

Comment: "What I want instead is a definition for sumValues such that the ks argument should, at compile time, be guaranteed to only contain keys that are present on the map" I don't see any way to do that. "ks" could be generated by something calling the code that contains the call to sumValues, andi it could have generated that in any way at all.

Comment: My guess here is that `sumValues` should then accept some implicit evidence that the list was taken from the list of possible keys. Adding in this detail.

Comment: I thin "accept some implicit evidence" is just wishful thinking.  Implicit evidence isn't a magic bullet for arbitary evidence, but all it does is say something about the types being used. It doesn't, and can't say anything about the values used. Consider that `ks` could be passed as `computeDependingOnPhaseOfMoon(theMapPassed` and at compile time, the details of what `computeDependingOnPhaseOfMoon` does are not available to the compiler to check - may be separately compiled. Knowledge of the types used in parameters and returned by it _is_ available.

Comment: Yeah. Been reading through the link on @Angelo Genovese 's answer though. Looks like path dependent types can be used.

Comment: Yep, reading that too but it's going a bit over my head right now.

Comment: Just thinking aloud, I don't claim to understand this yet. "whose calls to it can only compile if the ks argument is provably from the list of keys "  Or, you can only construct ks using keys from the map. Which (I think) is where that total map is coming from. If the keys  in `ks` of a type that is unique to the map, and there's no way of getting a value of that type except by querying the map, then `ks` must contain only keys from the map - and path-dependent types are a way of getting a type that is unique to that instance of the map. I think

Comment: Sounds about right. :)

Comment: Is the complete set of keys small and known at compile time?

Comment: No, the keys are not known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to map only the intersection (i.e. : between `m` keys and `ks`).

For example :

```
scala> def sumValues(m: Map[String, Int], ks: List[String]): Int = {
 |   m.keys.filter(ks.contains).map(m).sum
 | }
sumValues: (m: Map[String,Int], ks: List[String])Int

scala> val map = Map("hello" -> 5)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(hello -> 5)

scala> sumValues(map, List("hello", "world"))
res1: Int = 5
```

I think this solution is better than providing a default value because more generic (i.e. : you can use it not only with sums). However, I guess that this solution is less effective in term of performance because the intersection.

**EDIT** : As @jwvh pointed out in it message below, `ks.intersect(m.keys.toSeq).map(m).sum` is, to my opinion, more readable than `m.keys.filter(ks.contains).map(m).sum`.

Comment: Clever, but since you're getting the intersection it might be a little more direct to do: `ks.intersect(m.keys.toSeq).map(m).sum`

Comment: The main issue with this is it's not compile-time. Making it not throw an exception at run time is easy.